# How to align the menu bar in the middle using css and html 5?

Tags: css, html

I am working for my class project. I am trying to align the text of menus in the middle. I tried making modification on the css and searched internet and my book, but stilL could not fix the problem. Please help me the css and html code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>IT Career Center</title>
<meta charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="layout">
 <div class="pageHeader">
 <img src="headimg.jpg" alt="Header Image"> 
  </div>

 <ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
 <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Home</a>   </li>
 <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">IT Career</a></li>
 <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">BLS Data</a></li>
  <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Job Openings</a></li>
  <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Top IT College</a></li>
  <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Contact   Us</a></li>
  </ul>



  <div class="MainContent">
  </div>
 <div class="pageFooter">
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

css Code is below:

```
 body{
 background-image : url("background.jpg");
  background-attachment : fixed;
 background-size : 100% auto;
  }
 .layout{
  display : block;
  width : 900px;
 overflow : auto;
  margin : 2px auto 0 auto;
   }
 .PageHeader{
  float : left;
  clear : none;
  height : 200px;
  width : 900px;
   }

 .MainContent{
  background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 float : left;
 clear : none;
 height : 600px;
 width : 900px;
  }
 .pageFooter{
 background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 float : left;
  clear : none;
 height : 100px;
 width : 900px;
  }


ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
padding:0px 0px 0px 230px;
background-color:#ffffff;
background-repeat:repeat;
border-color:#AAAAAA;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
  }

 ul.pureCssMenu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.pureCssMenu {
 display:block;
 zoom:1;
 float: left;
  }
  ul.pureCssMenu ul{
  width:0px;
    }
  ul.pureCssMenu li{
   display:block;
   margin:2px 0px 0px 2px;
    font-size:0px;
     }

   ul.pureCssMenu a, ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover, ul.pureCssMenu   li.sep a:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-width:0px;
    border-color:#6655ff;
   border-style:solid;
   text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px;
   font:bold 20px Arial;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration:none;

    }


   ul.pureCssMenu li {
    float:left;
     }



 ul.pureCssMenu li a:hover{
position:relative;
background-color:#4792E6;
border-color:#665500;
border-style:solid;
font:bold 20px Arial;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Comment: [relevant!](http://howtocenterincss.com/) :P

Comment: That website didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.pureCssMenu {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 }
```

To center. That's the defacto way to center any objects. Also check out this CSS tricks article that will pretty much tell you how to center almost any object in CSS: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

remove `float: left;` for your `ul` and `li`
remove padding(-left) for your `ul`
add `text-align: center` to your `ul`
`li` elements should have `display: inline-block;`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2bys5bk/)